# Getting errors on new lighttpd installation gw_backend.c.324) child exited: 0 unix:/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket-0

Tags: php, lighttpd

The log includes the following two lines repeatedly. It seems to handle html just fine except I need to be able to run php on a regular basis.  :

```
(gw_backend.c.324) child exited: 0 unix:/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket-0
(gw_backend.c.468) unlink /var/run/lighttpd/php.socket-0 after connect failed: Connection refused
`
Here is the lighttpd.conf file:
`server.modules = (
    "mod_indexfile",
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_redirect",
        "mod_compress",
    "mod_dirlisting",
    "mod_staticfile",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/run/lighttpd/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 8078

# strict parsing and normalization of URL for consistency and security
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_http-parseoptsDetails
# (might need to explicitly set "url-path-2f-decode" = "disable"
#  if a specific application is encoding URLs inside url-path)
server.http-parseopts = (
  "header-strict"           => "enable",# default
  "host-strict"             => "enable",# default
  "host-normalize"          => "enable",# default
  "url-normalize-unreserved"=> "enable",# recommended highly
  "url-normalize-required"  => "enable",# recommended
  "url-ctrls-reject"        => "enable",# recommended
  "url-path-2f-decode"      => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-2f-reject"      => "enable",
  "url-path-dotseg-remove"  => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-dotseg-reject"  => "enable",
 #"url-query-20-plus"       => "enable",# consistency in query string
)

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.conf.pl"
include "/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/*.conf"

#server.compat-module-load   = "disable"
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
                     "bin-path" => "/bin/php7.4",
                     "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket",
                     "max-procs" => 1,
                     "bin-environment" => (
                       "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "16",
                       "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                     ),
                     "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
                 )))
```

conf-enabled contains:

```
ls conf-enabled/
10-fastcgi.conf  90-javascript-alias.conf
```

Whereas 10-fastcgi.conf is:

```
cat conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf 
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/fastcgi.txt.gz
# http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOptions#mod_fastcgi-fastcgi

server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
```

I think that's all.  Let me know if there is something I've overlooked. The socket is owned by www-data,

ls -l /var/run/lighttpd/php.socket-0

srwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 0 Nov  1 13:36 /var/run/lighttpd/php.socket-0

And running the app with -D from the command line didn't produce any errors.

sudo lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: "Getting errors on new lighttpd installation" -> Have you ever gotten PHP working?  I think you should start with basic documentation.  https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_fastcgi is one good place to start.  Another would be a "how-to" for lighttpd for whatever Linux distro you are using, which appears to be Debian-based, and appears to be woefully out-of-date if you're using php 7.4 (https://www.php.net/releases/index.php)

Comment: I've exhausted the "how to" docs I found on-line.  I've reconfigured multiple times using those docs and I finally gave up and asked.  Yes, it's an older Ubuntu distro, but there is another primary application on the system that requires more effort to upgrade than I currently have time to perform.  I know for sure that when this version of the os/lighttpd/php7.4 was current that lighttpd would serve php files.  Thanks for the observation and assist.